# Origin of "The first step is always the hardest"

Tags: etymology, proverbs

I'm looking for the period when the American proverb *The first step is always the hardest* first appeared. Google Ngram won't let me do the search because the phrase contains more than 5 symbols.

Comment: @Josh61 I'm looking for _the time it first appeared_ (roughly, of course), not _the time it became common_.

Comment: @Josh61 how did you come to this conclusion? I'm not doubting the correctness of the answer, just being curious.

Comment: The French equivalent "[Il n'y a que le premier pas qui coûte](http://www.leparisien.fr/espace-premium/air-du-temps/il-n-y-a-que-le-premier-pas-qui-coute-15-07-2013-2983285.php#xtref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.fr)" (*It is only the first step that costs*) may be traced in 1763 - by Mme du Deffand-.

Comment: Fer cryin' out loud!!  Just search for "step is always the hardest".  You'll get an 1879 reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the ***The Facts on File Dictionary of Proverbs*** the saying is popularly associated with the story of Saint Danis:

***[The first step is always the hardest](https://books.google.it/books?id=fgaUQc8NbTYC&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=the%20first%20step%20is%20always%20the%20hardest%20origin&source=bl&ots=eUC0egloM1&sig=QK1acuNvi4DhrpIYB7cytXj_HO4&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq5qaew8LKAhUBHiwKHdcuBU0Q6AEIUDAP#v=onepage&q=the%20first%20step%20is%20always%20the%20hardest%20origin&f=false):***

Meaning:

> - Making a start is often the most difficult part of a journey

Origin:

> - This proverb was first recorded c. 1596 in the form of  ***"The first stretch (of a journey) is the worst."*** It is popularly associated with the story of Saint Danis, patron of France, who walked several miles with his head in his hands after being executed, and on learning of this, a French nobleman remarked "C'e n'est que la premiere focus que coute" (It is only the first time that counts).
> - Variant of this proverb: It is the first step that is difficult.

- Evidence of usage in  its current common form "The first step is always the hardest" is  from the second half of the 19th century according to ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=step%20is%20always%20the%20hardest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstep%20is%20always%20the%20hardest%3B%2Cc0)***.
- It [earliest](https://archive.org/details/inyear13taleofme00reutrich) usage I could find is from [In the Year '13: A Tale of Mecklenburg](https://books.google.it/books?id=y585AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA287&dq=%22step%20is%20always%20the%20hardest%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilnazussLKAhXMEywKHRV5Dl4Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22step%20is%20always%20the%20hardest%22&f=false) in 1869:

> - *Heinrich," cried he, "the first step is always the hardest, as the Devil said when he began to carry millstones, but " here he ...*

Comment: In the play of Anthony Munday (159x), revised by Shakespeare, ["Sir Thomas More"](https://www.playshakespeare.com/sir-thomas-more/scenes/1194-act-ii-scene-5): *Would I wear so fair on my journey! the first stretch is the worst, me thinks*.